# Dual boot EFI and legacy CSM system

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, uefi, live-usb, iso

I want to create a Live-Linux system on USB that can dual boot EFI and legacy CSM system. I know one distribution that can do that -- grml, but

- I want to know the tricks under the hood, and
- The biggest downside of grml is that I must use a FAT32 partition for it to boot.

Can grub2 handle both EFI and legacy CSM system at the same time?

Comment: UEFI only boots from an ESP - efi system partition which must be FAT32 with esp/boot flags. See: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259682 Newer info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi

Comment: Oh well, that, I can accept as the reality and the answer. Thanks @oldfred.

Comment: Very new UEFI systems are now UEFI only, no CSM/Legacy/BIOS boot option. Lenovo announced all 2020 products will be UEFI only (UEFI Class 3 or no CSM).
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht510878-legacy-bios-boot-support-removed-in-lenovo-2020-products
 I have multiple flash drives and for my one very old BIOS only system prefer to just have a separate flash drive in BIOS mode for it. All others are UEFI. I also put at least a small install with a few repair tools on every drive, even those just for data.